# Can we get a draft feature?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, sandbox

Instead of posting all our drafts to the Sandbox, could we just add a draft feature to the main site?

Answer (score 3):

## No

Questions like this would be problems for both the Main site and the Meta site as they cause more problems than they solve.

### Main

Drafts would either get confused as actual posts, causing people to attempt a challenge without a full spec, or they would be closed as off-topic as they wouldn't actually be challenges. This would also encourage new users to post challenges with very bare specs, thinking it was ok given the example we would have set.

### Meta

At the moment, the Sandbox has over 1700 undeleted posts in it, and (I think) around 4360 deleted and undeleted total. If this number of questions were asked on meta, genuine questions like this one would disappear into the ether and go unanswered. Not to mention the fact that meta would be flooded with hundreds of posts that, personally, I would close as duplicates of the Sandbox. And when a new user doesn't know about the Sandbox and asks a "read my draft" question on meta, it is quickly shut down as a dupe.

### Overall

While it could work (probably not), I think that it would

- cause unnecessary clutter on whatever site they were posted on
- be closed as either dupes or off topic
- confuse new users about what the site is designed for (which already happens a lot)
- degrade the quality of the site in general

Comment: "they would be closed as off-topic as they wouldn't actually be challenges" closing would be disabled for drafts. They could be deleted if they had nothing to do with code golf at all.

Comment: @PyRulez that would involve even more custom work for PPCG and wouldn't please mother meta

Comment: Drafting would be useful for any site, I think. It would basically be turning sandbox into an actual feature.

Comment: @PyRulez we are an exceptional case. Normally, if someone wants to use SE, its to ask a question, something which doesn't need refining before posting. Assuming they're clear with what they ask, there is no issue. Whereas here, challenges need a lot of rules and clarifications before posting, so we need the Sandbox. As it isn't needed on other sites, SE isn't going to implement it just for us just as much as they will make upvotes +10.

Comment: There are currently 4358 sandbox posts total. We won't reach 20,000 for a while yet